# Modelling an ER diagram situation

Tags: sql, database-design, erd

I have two entities named "Main office" and "Branch office", which belong to some company. The main office can have 1 or more branch offices.

But, a company can have only one Main office, which is a central place for all other main offices. How should I model this situation?

1. Use 2 entities, `Main` and `Branch`, where `Main` will have a boolean attribute `Central`. I think this is bad as it will lead to transitive dependency?
2. Have 3 entities, `Main`, `Branch` and `Central`, where the `Central` office table will have only one row?
3. Or, in the end, to have 2 entities `Main` and `Branch`, where `Main` will be in relationship with itself.

EDIT: 
A company can have more than one main office.

Comment: What is the difference between the main office and the central office?  And, is your question about how to set up the logical diagram for the entities or what tables to have in the database?

Comment: Your edit contradicts what you said earlier: *company have only one Main office*. Please present yout requirements so that your post is consistent.

Comment: Probably you should revisit the names of your entities, they are prone to ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

For modeling purposes, you would probably have three entities:  company, main office, branch offices.  Company would have a 1 to many relationship with main office; main office would have a 0 to many relationship with branch office.  This seems to capture the *logical* structure of the data.

I think you are also asking about the physical structure.  Logical structures can be mapped directly onto physical structures, but that is not necessary.  The question becomes how the data is going to be used.

One reasonable implementation of the logical model would have a company table and single offices table, with:

- a flag that specifies whether it is a main office or a branch office
- a self-join key for branch offices to point back to the main office, with the constraint that the "match back" has to be a main office
- a bunch of fields common to all offices
- a small number of fields common to one or the other type

Another reasonable implementation would put main offices and branch offices in different tables.  This comes closer to the logical model of the data.  However, I imagine that a lot of queries would be union'ing these two tables, making the single table approach more efficient in practice (but not necessarily).

Unfortunately, relational databases don't implement the idea of class inheritance very well.

Answer (score 1):

Create Entity `Company` and `Entity` Office.  Create 1 to M relationship from `Company` to `Office`.  Office has a type - either `Main` or `Branch`.  Create 1 to M relationship from `Office` to itself.  This recursive relationship is the association of a branch office to a main office.  Finally add a 1 to 1 relationship from Office back to Company, with a role name to distinguish the relationship as identifying the `Central` Office.

You could also make Office a super type and make Main and Branch sub-types.  This would enable you to model a 1 to M relationship from Main to Branch and more explicitly show the business rule.

It would be great if I could paste an ER model fragment in here!  The key point is that Office is the only real entity here, and main and branch are sub-types of Office.  Central is not an entity at all but is a relationship role between an office and the company.

Answer (score 0):

Make a one-to-one relationship between `Main office` and `Company`, then a many-to-one between `Branch office` and `Main office`.

There is no direct relationship between `Branch office` and `Company`, but it can be easily inferred transitively through the `Main office`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use inheritance in your E-R model. You have a generic Office superclass and Branch/Main subclasses. Company will have a Many to One relationship with Main Office and a One to One relationship with Main Office to represent the central office.